# Ruby SAML ACS Logout Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-saml

I have created a SAML2 SSO Login(with google assertion consumer service) as follows:

```
require 'onelogin/ruby-saml'

class Saml
  class << self
    def init(provider, saml2_idp_url, saml2_issuer_url)
      request = OneLogin::RubySaml::Authrequest.new

      request.create(saml_settings)
    end

    def consume(params)
      OneLogin::RubySaml::Response.new(params[:SAMLResponse], :settings => saml_settings)
    end

    private

    def saml_settings
      idp_metadata_parser = OneLogin::RubySaml::IdpMetadataParser.new

      settings = idp_metadata_parser.parse( File.read("acs.xml") )

      settings.assertion_consumer_service_url = https://certedrive-dev1.ngrok.io/saml2/idp?idpid=xxxxxx
      settings.issuer                         = https://certedrive-dev1.ngrok.io/saml2?idpid=xxxxxx
      settings
    end
  end
end
```

But, I'm unable to get the equivalent logout with ACS.

I tried:

```
logout_req = OneLogin::RubySaml::Logoutrequest.new
logout_req_url = logout_req.create(saml_settings)
```

But, this throws me:

> NoMethodError - undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

I feel the Logout method I'm trying is wrong. What may be the correct way to send out Logout request?

Answer (score 2):

Check the code of the [ruby-saml-example](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example) project.

The [logout](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example/blob/master/app/controllers/saml_controller.rb#L45) method handles SP and IdP initiaited SLO flow.

In the use case that you are describing, I think the problem is that you have not defined the [idp_slo_target_url](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example/blob/master/app/models/account.rb#L22) attribute at the settings.
In ruby-saml-example, that issue is controlled in that [line](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example/blob/master/app/controllers/saml_controller.rb#L65).

For more info, read at ruby-saml's README, the [single-log-out](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml#single-log-out) section.